# Converting from curl to python request.post

Tags: python, curl

I wish to convert my current curl command to python code to request for access token for an api.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"grantType":"client_credentials"}' [Access Token URL]
```

my attempt:

```
import requests

api_url_base = "https://api.example.com/api/"
headers ={'Content_Type':'application/json',
        'grandType': 'client_credentials'
        }

response = requests.post(headers=headers, "https://api.example.com/accesstokens")
if response.status_code == 200:
    print(json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8')))
else:
    print(response.status_code)
```

Expected output:
Should be in python.

Comment: Does it not work? If so how?

Comment: Does this code work? What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You're mismatching posting headers and body data there, not to mention there's a typo with `grandType`.

Either way, posting JSON and parsing JSON responses is super easy with Requests:

```py
response = requests.post(
    "https://api.example.com/accesstokens",
    json={"grantType": "client_credentials"},
)
response.raise_for_status()  # raise an exception for error statuses
data = response.json()
print(data)
```